# regex - Substitute a string till you encounter second capital letter

Tags: python, regex, string, regex-negation

I have a string which may have multiple instances of substrings with the pattern of `"WORLD/XyzRights"`, `"WORLD/abcNext"`. That is, the `"WORLD"` followed by `"/"` and then a word, and another word starting with capital letter. I want to replace the string to `"Rights"` and `"Next"` respectively.

That is the expected output is : removing the `"World/string"` till the next capital letter although the letter just after the `"/"` can also be capital, but we should remove that too. So, in the above 2 cases : 
`"Rights"` and `"Next"`

I tried this :

```
re.sub("""WORLD\/[A-Za-z]+(.*?)[^A-Z]""", " ", completeText, flags=re.S)
```

But, this removes `"Rights"` and `"Next"` also and keeps the remaining string

Comment: what's your expected output?

Comment: @AvinashRaj - I have edited the question to better explain the expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add an optional pattern to match the first captial letter which exists next to `/`.

```
>>> import re
>>> s = ["WORLD/XyzRights", "WORLD/abcNext"]
>>> [re.sub(r'WORLD/[A-Z]?[a-z]+([A-Z])', r'\1', i) for i in s]
['Rights', 'Next']
>>>
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: This pattern would not capture the final word in a camelcase expression of arbitrary length, [see here](http://rextester.com/UGEEL81319).  Not sure if that matters to the OP, just wanted to drop a small note.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - Ya, this case would not occur for me. But, thanks a lot for the insight. Never would have thought it that way. :)

Answer (score 1):

I would use the following pattern for replacement:

```
WORLD/.*([A-Z].*)
```

And then just replace with the captured group `\1`.  This says to greedily match and consume everything after the first slash until hitting the *last* capital letter, which is the start of the word we want to capture.  Then, capture that final word and use it in the replacement.

```
re.sub("""WORLD/.*([A-Z].*)""", r"\1", "WORLD/XyzRights", flags=re.S)
```

## Demo

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you always have at least one character before your word that you want to keep after '/', you can try the following regular expression:

```
WORLD/[a-zA-Z][^A-Z]*
```

to match your pattern to be removed. It works for both of your examples.